# How can I use async methods in non-async (sync) overrides?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I browsed through other questions on StackOverflow, but none of the other questions/answers appears to match my case:

I have written an `async` method in a class that I need to call from an overridden method in another class that derives from a .NET `System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet` class.

I would usually call my method like this:

```cs
public async Task TestReadingFile()
{
  using MyReader reader = new MyReader(SetupMyStream("Contoso.txt"));

  await foreach (MyDataObject obj in reader.GetFrames())
  {
    Debug.Print($"{reader.Progress}: {obj.GetType().Name} - {obj}");
  }
}
```

Now, in my class's `ProcessRecord` override of the `Cmdlet` base class I cannot use `async`. But, of course, I want to await the result.

How can I do this?

My expectation was to use something like this:

```cs
protected override void ProcessRecord()
{
  using MyReader reader = new MyReader(MyFilePath);

  IAsyncEnumerator<MyDataObject> enumerator = reader.GetFrames().GetAsyncEnumerator();

  while (enumerator.MoveNextAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult())
  {
    MyDataObject obj = enumerator.Current;

    Debug.Print($"{reader.Progress}: {obj.GetType().Name} - {obj}");
  }
}
```

But this approach throws an `InvalidOperationException`.

How is this done the right way?

Comment: 1. `IAsyncEnumerator`'s `MoveNext` returns `ValueTask`, which cannot be synchronously waited. You should call `MoveNextAsync().AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead. 2. Enumerator is disposable, so you should use `using` keyword for enumerator.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You've been a great help. If you want to convert your comment into an answer I will gladly vote for it. — However, I cannot use `using` on IAsynEnumerator. If I do, I get an error asking me to use `async using`, which I – for apparent reasons – cannot use. How would you suggest to use `using` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you get `InvalidOperationException` is fact that `ValueTask`'s cannot be synchronously waited, as `Task`'s can. So simple solution is to just turn it to `Task` with `AsTask()` method.

Enumerators are disposable, which mean you should dispose them after usage. While `IEnumerator` inherits `IDisposable`, `IAsyncEnumerator` inherits `IAsyncDisposable`. In normal situation you should've been using `await using` but since method is synchronous, we have to lower this thing ourselves. First, convert this to `try-finally` construction and then synchronously wait on returned task.

```cs
protected override void ProcessRecord()
{
  using MyReader reader = new MyReader(MyFilePath);

  IAsyncEnumerator<MyDataObject> enumerator = reader.GetFrames().GetAsyncEnumerator();

  try
  {
     while (enumerator.MoveNextAsync().AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult())
     {
       MyDataObject obj = enumerator.Current;

       Debug.Print($"{reader.Progress}: {obj.GetType().Name} - {obj}");
     }
  }
  finally
  {
      enumerator?.DisposeAsync().AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
  }
}
```